# Understanding pthreads locks and condition variables

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I had an exercise about threads, locks, and condition variables in C. I needed to write a program that get data, turn it into a linked list, starting 3 threads each calculating result for each node in the list and main thread printing the results after evreyone finished.

This is the main function:

```
int thread_finished_count;

// Lock and Conditional variable
pthread_mutex_t list_lock;
pthread_mutex_t thread_lock;
pthread_cond_t thread_cv;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    node *list;
    int pairs_count, status;
    thread_finished_count = 0;

    /* get the data and start the threads */
    node *head = create_numbers(argc, argv, &pairs_count);
    list = head; // backup head for results
    pthread_t *threads = start_threads(&list);

    /* wait for threads and destroy lock */
    status = pthread_cond_wait(&thread_cv, &list_lock);
    chcek_status(status);
    status = pthread_mutex_destroy(&list_lock);
    chcek_status(status);
    status = pthread_mutex_destroy(&thread_lock);
    chcek_status(status);

    /* print result in original list */
    print_results(head);

    /* cleanup */
    wait_for_threads(threads, NUM_THREADS);
    free_list(head);
    free(threads);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note that the create_numbers function is working properly, and the list is working as intended.

Here is the start_thread and thread_function code:

```
pthread_t *start_threads(node **list)
{
    int status;
    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * NUM_THREADS);
    check_malloc(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, list);
        chcek_status(status);
    }
    return threads;
}

void *thread_function(node **list)
{
    int status, self_id = pthread_self();
    printf("im in %u\n", self_id);
    node *currentNode;

    while (1)
    {
        if (!(*list))
            break;
        status = pthread_mutex_lock(&list_lock);
        chcek_status(status);
        printf("list location %p thread %u\n", *list, self_id);
        if (!(*list))
        {
            status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);
            chcek_status(status);
            break;
        }
        currentNode = (*list);
        (*list) = (*list)->next;
        status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);
        chcek_status(status);
        currentNode->gcd = gcd(currentNode->num1, currentNode->num2);
        status = usleep(10);
        chcek_status(status);
    }
    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_lock);
    chcek_status(status);
    thread_finished_count++;
    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_lock);
    chcek_status(status);
    if (thread_finished_count != 3)
        return NULL;
    status = pthread_cond_signal(&thread_cv);
    chcek_status(status);
    return NULL;
}
void chcek_status(int status)
{
    if (status != 0)
    {
        fputs("pthread_function() error\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Note that self_id is used for debugging purposes.

## My problem

1. My main problem is about splitting the work. Each thread so get an element from the global linked list, calculate gcd, then go on and take the next element. I get this effect only if I'm adding usleep(10) after I unlock the mutex in the while loop. If I don't add the usleep, the FIRST thread will go in and do all the work while other thread just wait and come in after all the work has been done.

Please note!: I thought about the option that maybe the first thread is created, and untill the second thread is created the first one already finish all the jobs. This is why I added the "I'm in #threadID" check with usleep(10) when evrey thread is created. They all come in but only first one is doing all the jobs.
Here is the output example if I do usleep after the mutex unlock (notice diffrent thread ID)

**with usleep**

```
./v2 nums.txt
im in 1333593856
list location 0x7fffc4fb56a0 thread 1333593856
im in 1316685568
im in 1325139712
list location 0x7fffc4fb56c0 thread 1333593856
list location 0x7fffc4fb56e0 thread 1316685568
list location 0x7fffc4fb5700 thread 1325139712
list location 0x7fffc4fb5720 thread 1333593856
list location 0x7fffc4fb5740 thread 1316685568
list location 0x7fffc4fb5760 thread 1325139712
list location 0x7fffc4fb5780 thread 1333593856
list location 0x7fffc4fb57a0 thread 1316685568
list location 0x7fffc4fb57c0 thread 1325139712
list location 0x7fffc4fb57e0 thread 1333593856
list location 0x7fffc4fb5800 thread 1316685568
list location (nil) thread 1325139712
list location (nil) thread 1333593856
...
normal result output
...
```

And thats the output if I comment out the usleep after mutex lock (Notice the same thread ID)
**without usleep**

```
  ./v2 nums.txt
im in 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b946a0 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b946c0 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b946e0 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b94700 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b94720 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b94740 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b94760 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b94780 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b947a0 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b947c0 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b947e0 thread 2631730944
list location 0x7fffe5b94800 thread 2631730944
im in 2623276800
im in 2614822656
...
normal result output
...
```

2. My second question is about order of threads working. My exercise ask me to not use join to synchronize the threads (only use at the end to "free resources") but instand use that condition variable.

My goal is that each thread will take element, do the calculation and in the meanwhile another thread will go in and take another element, and new thread will take each element (or at least close to that)

Thanks for reading and I appriciate your help.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE].  `As a result only the first thread do ALL the work,` Synchronizing is not ordering. Possible explanation is that your system just picks the first thread to be executed all the time or first thread finishes all the work before two other get started, etc. `But why is that?` To answer a specific question about your specific code behavior, you have to show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are doing the `gcd()` work while holding the lock... so *(a)* only one thread will do any work at any one time, though *(b)* that does not entirely explain why only one thread appears to do (nearly) all the work -- as KamilCuk says, it may be that there is so little work to do, that it's (nearly) all done before the second thread wakes up properly.  [More exotic, there may be some latency between thread 'a' unlocking the mutex and another thread starting to run, such that thread 'a' can acquire the mutex before another thread gets there.]

POSIX says that when a mutex is unlocked, if there are waiters then "the scheduling policy shall determine which thread shall acquire the mutex".  The default "scheduling policy" is (to the best of my knowledge) implementation defined.

You could try a couple of things: *(1)* use a `pthread_barrier_t` to hold all the threads at the start of `thread_function()` until they are all running; *(2)* use `sched_yield(void)` after `pthread_mutex_unlock()` to prompt the system into running the newly runnable thread.

Second, you should not under any circumstance treat a 'condition variable' as a signal.  For `main()` to know that all threads have finished you need a count -- which could be a `pthread_barrier_t`; or it could be simple integer, protected by a mutex, with a 'condition variable' to hold the main thread on while it waits; or it could be a count (in `main()`) and a semaphore (posted once by each thread as it exits).

Third, you show `pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);` in `main()`.  At that point `main()` *must* own `lock`... and it matters when that happened.  But: as it stands, the *first* thread to find the `list` empty will kick `cv`, and `main()` will proceed, even though other threads are still running.  Though once `main()` does re-acquire `lock`, any threads which are then still running will either be exiting or will be stuck on the `lock`.  (It's a mess.)

---

In general, the template for using a 'condition variable' is:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&...lock) ;

    while (!(... thing we need ...))
      pthread_cond_wait(&...cond_var, &...lock) ;

    ... do stuff now we have what we need ....

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&...lock) ;
```

NB: a 'condition variable' does not have a value... despite the name, it is *not* a flag to signal that some condition is true.  A 'condition variable' is, essentially, a queue of threads waiting to be re-started.  When a 'condition variable' is signaled, at least one waiting thread will be re-started -- but if there are no threads waiting, *nothing* happens, in particular the (so called) 'condition variable' retains *no memory* of the signal.

In the new code, following the above template, `main()` should:

```
    /* wait for threads .... */

    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_lock);
    chcek_status(status);

    while (thread_finished_count != 3)
      {
        pthread_cond_wait(&thread_cv, &thread_lock) ;
        chcek_status(status);
      } ;

    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_lock) ;
    chcek_status(status);
```

So what is going on here ?

1. `main()` is waiting for `thread_finished_count == 3`
2. `thread_finished_count` is a shared variable "protected" by the `thread_lock` mutex.

   ...so it is incremented in `thread_function()` under the mutex.

   ...and `main()` must also read it under the mutex.
3. if `main()` finds `thread_finished_count != 3` it must wait.

   to do that it does: `pthread_cond_wait(&thread_cv, &thread_lock)`, which:

   - unlocks `thread_lock`
   - places the thread on the `thread_cv` queue of waiting threads.

   and it does those *atomically*.
4. when `thread_function()` does the `pthread_cond_signal(&thread_cv)` it wakes up the waiting thread.
5. when the `main()` thread wakes up, it will first re-acquire the `thread_lock`...

   ...so it can then proceed to re-read `thread_finished_count`, to see if it is now `3`.

FWIW: I recommend *not* destroying the mutexes etc until *after* all the threads have been joined.

Comment: Thank you for the informative response! Please check my post as I updated some stuff and I change the thread_function according to your (a) advice. But even after that only one thread is doing all the work (if I dont use usleep). I also tried sched_yield() after the unlock, And for some reason that work for the first time. So the first thread going in, doing the first element, and then the second thread take control on the second element, and the second thread is doing all the rest of the jobs. I guess thats better than one thread doing it all, but still not what I was looking to get.

Comment: And last thing about the cond_wait. I notice that there is a problem where main kicks back to work before all the thread exit. I will try to implement another mutex and another cv to save the int counter that will count amount of threads finished. But I still dont understand what happened before this, when only one thread is doing all the work. Is there a way to change scheduling policy mabye? I dont understand why the usleep fixing it but it doesnt work without it

Comment: I don't see where `lock` and `cv` are initialised.  I don't see where `main()` acquires `lock` before the `pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);` in `main()`.  The     `pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);` in `main()` seems premature... there may still be threads waiting on it.  You are not checking return codes on any of the `pthread_xxx()` functions... so it's possible that things are not working, but the code is ignoring that.  I should fix all that and getting the main thread to wait until all others have finished, before worrying about anything else.

Comment: Thank you again for the comment. I updated again the code with your good feedback. I make sure all the threads are finished now but I did not really understand what you meant with "main() acquires lock before wait". But overall I tried some outputs after those revisions but still same result: with usleep, evreything works perfect. without usleep - only one thread do all the work... any more ideas? because im out of any haha

Comment: I have added a note on how to correctly use a 'condition variable'.  I have played with this for a while, and yes, the sequence of threads which do the work is peculiar.  I tried a `pthread_barrier_t` at the start of the `thread_function()`, and that made a difference.  I also tried `for (volatile unsigned delay = 0 ; delay < (1000 * 1000) ; ++delay) ;` instead of `usleep(10)`, and that too made a difference. But I do not entirely understand what is going on here.

Comment: As I said, my best guess is that `pthread_mutex_signal()` does not *instantly* transfer ownership of the mutex to one of the waiting threads.  So if a thread signals the mutex, and then very quickly waits on it again, it may be able to grab ownership of the mutex back again.  You could try tidying up the code and asking the question again ?

Comment: Hey Chris I really appriciate you taking time to help me on this one. I must say i did not fully understand the notes you made and your lateast comments. My thought process: I have global int counting finished threads, i have a list mutex lock and the counter mutex lock along with one conditional variable. The main thread is starting the threads, then waiting untill the condition variable is met. While he wait the threads do their work with the last, and when a threads go out of the loop he lock the counter, increment and check if the rest finished if yes he signal the main which then continue

Comment: I did not fully understand what you did in your last edit. Why you have new mutex lock for condition variable (cond_lock)? If the main is locking "thread lock" which is the counter lock, how can the rest of the threads increment it by one when they are finished? I really did not understand the last part of the edit. Do you think it would be better if I upload my entire code? So it would be possible to just copy , complie, and run it?I also sent a message to my teacher, mabye he will have an answer for this (which i will share of course)

Comment: I've tidied up a little.  In particular, `cond_lock` in the recommended code for `main()` was a cut-and-paste snafu (sorry).  The problem with  'condition variables' is that they really don't do what most people expect them to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked deeper into how glibc (v2.30 on Linux & x86_64, at least) implements `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `_unlock()`.

It turns out that `_lock()` works something like this:

```
  if (atomic_cmp_xchg(mutex->lock, 0, 1))
    return <OK> ;             // mutex->lock was 0, is now 1

  while (1)
    {
      if (atomic_xchg(mutex->lock, 2) == 0)
        return <OK> ;        // mutex->lock was 0, is now 2

      ...do FUTEX_WAIT(2)... // suspend thread iff mutex->lock == 2...
    } ;
```

And `_unlock()` works something like this:

```
  if (atomic_xchg(mutex->lock, 0) == 2)  // set mutex->lock == 0
    ...do FUTEX_WAKE(1)...               // if may have waiter(s) start 1
```

Now:

- `mutex->lock`: 0 => unlocked, 1 => locked-but-no-waiters, 2 => locked-with-waiter(s)

  'locked-but-no-waiters' optimizes for the case where there is no lock contention and there is no need to do `FUTEX_WAKE` in `_unlock()`.
- the `_lock()`/`_unlock()` functions are in the library -- they are *not* in the kernel.

  ...in particular, the ownership of the mutex is a matter for the library, *not* the kernel.
- `FUTEX_WAIT(2)` is a call to the kernel, which will place the thread on a pending queue associated with the mutex, unless `mutex->lock != 2`.

  The kernel checks for `mutex->lock == 2` and adds the thread to the queue *atomically*.  This deals with the case of `_unlock()` being called after the `atomic_xchg(mutex->lock, 2)`.
- `FUTEX_WAKE(1)` is also a call to the kernel, and the `futex` man page tells us:

  > FUTEX_WAKE (since Linux 2.6.0)
  >
  > This  operation  wakes at most *'val'* of the waiters that are waiting ...  No guarantee is provided about which waiters are awoken (e.g., a waiter with a higher scheduling priority is not guaranteed to be awoken in preference to a waiter with a lower priority).

  where *'val'* in this case is 1.

  Although the documentation says "no guarantee about which waiters are awoken", the queue appears to be at least FIFO.

Note especially that:

1. `_unlock()` does *not* pass the mutex to the thread started by the `FUTEX_WAKE`.
2. once woken up, the thread will again try to obtain the lock...

   ...but may be beaten to it by any other running thread -- including the thread which just did the `_unlock()`.

I believe this is why you have not seen the work being shared across the threads.  There is so little work for each one to do, that a thread can unlock the mutex, do the work and be back to lock the mutex again *before* a thread woken up by the unlock can get going and succeed in locking the mutex.